# Using sed replace line in file with another file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a very large tab delimited file, I would like to replace a single line in this file with another. As the line has >100 columns, a simple sed 's/find/replace/' is not desirable. My newline is stored in file newline.txt

How do I achieve:

```
sed 's/find/newline.txt/' infile
```

Comment: To clarify, I would like to 'find' a subsection of the line and then replace the whole line

Comment: `sed "s/^.*find.*$/$(cat newline.txt)/"` ?

Comment: Not sure I understand, if you find a certain pattern in your original file then you would like the entire line to be replaced by a corresponding line in newline.txt?  Does this mean the pattern is unique and only returns one line?

Comment: @dood - yes that is correct. In this example the find pattern is unique and so will return 1 line

Comment: Thanks @Aaron that works

Comment: If performance is important, there might be better methods (something like putting the newLine in the `h`old buffer then e`x`changing the matching line with it)

Comment: The above response by @Aaron has answered my question the best, though I am unable to indicate this as it is a comment

Comment: @tc13 I'm currently enjoying holidays so I can't be bothered to write an answer. Feel free to post your own referencing my comment and credit it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @Aaron

```
sed "s/^.*find.*$/$(cat newline.txt)/" infile.txt
```

Where *find* is a unique string in infile.txt that returns a single line, the line is then replaced by newline.txt

Answer (score 14):

With GNU sed:

Find line in file `file.csv` which contains `find`, append content (`r`) of file `newline.txt` and delete (`d`) line which contains `find`:

```
sed -e '/find/{r newline.txt' -e 'd}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on GNU sed 4.2.2, also includes answers from [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39411657/4082052) and [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411539/replace-line-in-file-with-another-file#comment66147472_39411539)

```
$ cat foo.txt 
1 abc
2 ijk!
3 pqr
4 xyz

$ cat f1.txt 
a/b/c

$ cat f2.txt 
line

$ cat f3.txt 
line a
line b
```

1) Pattern and replacement not containing characters that'll affect `sed` command or act weirdly due to `bash` substitution inside double quotes

```
$ sed "/3/c $(< f2.txt)" foo.txt 
1 abc
2 ijk!
line
4 xyz

$ sed "s/.*3.*/$(< f2.txt)/" foo.txt 
1 abc
2 ijk!
line
4 xyz

$ sed -e '/3/{r f2.txt' -e 'd}' foo.txt 
1 abc
2 ijk!
line
4 xyz
```

2) Pattern getting affected due to `bash` substitution

```
$ sed "/!/c $(< f2.txt)" foo.txt 
bash: !/c: event not found

$ sed '/!/c '"$(< f2.txt)" foo.txt
1 abc
line
3 pqr
4 xyz

$ sed "s/.*!.*/$(< f2.txt)/" foo.txt 
bash: !.*/$: event not found

$ sed 's/.*!.*/'"$(< f2.txt)/" foo.txt
1 abc
line
3 pqr
4 xyz

$ sed -e '/!/{r f2.txt' -e 'd}' foo.txt 
1 abc
line
3 pqr
4 xyz
```

3) Replacement line (single line only) containing characters affecting `sed`

```
$ sed "/3/c $(< f1.txt)" foo.txt 
1 abc
2 ijk!
a/b/c
4 xyz

$ sed "s/.*3.*/$(< f1.txt)/" foo.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'

$ sed "s|.*3.*|$(< f1.txt)|" foo.txt
1 abc
2 ijk!
a/b/c
4 xyz

$ sed -e '/3/{r f1.txt' -e 'd}' foo.txt
1 abc
2 ijk!
a/b/c
4 xyz
```

4) Replacement with multiple lines

```
$ sed "/3/c $(< f3.txt)" foo.txt 
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: extra characters after command

$ sed "s/.*3.*/$(< f3.txt)/" foo.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command

$ sed -e '/3/{r f3.txt' -e 'd}' foo.txt
1 abc
2 ijk!
line a
line b
4 xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sed s/find/$(< newline.txt)/ infile
```